# Creating an object stack class - where did I go wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm still new to Java and I'm trying to create a general purpose stack queue that uses an object array. I known that I've done things incorrectly, namely declaring the arrays and assigning the array lengths.

Can someone take a look and give me some feedback?

```
public class GeneralStack
{
    GeneralStack [] stack;  //not sure how to declare this
    private int count;
    private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 100;

//default constructor
public GeneralStack()
    {
        stack = new int[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
        count = 0;
    }

//alternate constructor
public GeneralStack (int maxCapacity)
    {
        stack = new int[maxCapacity];
        count = setCount;
    }

//accessor getCount
public int getCount ()
    {
    return count;
    }

//accessor isEmpty
public boolean isEmpty ()
    {
    boolean isEmpty=false;
    if (count == 0);
        {
            isEmpty=true;
        }
    return isEmpty;
    }

//accessor isFull
public boolean isFull ()
    {
    boolean isFull=false;
    if (count == maxCapacity);
        {
        isFull=true;
        }
    return isFull;
    }

//mutator push
public void push (int value)
    {
    if (isFull ())
        {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Stack is full");
        }
    else
        {
        stack[value]; //not sure how to assign value to the stack
        count++;
        }
    }

//mutator pop
public void pop ()
    {
         int topVal = top();
        count = count-1;
        return topVal;
    }

//accessor top
public int topVal ()
    {
    if (isEmpty())
        {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Stack is empty");
        }
    else 
        {
        topVal=stack[count-1];
        }
    return topVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what do you want? For people to rewrite it for you?

Comment: Unless there's a specific issue you want help with, consider posting this on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Tbh, if you're gonna be using something stack-like like that, just use an ArrayList. Much easier. However, if you want to make an array stack, so be it. However, there are a lot of error's in that code. I suggest getting an IDE to help you (such as Eclipse). This isn't a site where you post your code, and tell people to fix it.

Comment: @AlexColeman an [ArrayDeque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) is a more fitting alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `stack` appears to have been intended to be an array of the element type, which `push(int)` tells me is `int`.
2. What kind of *general* stack is limited to `int`?
3. `setCount` appears to have been intended to be `maxCapacity` in the `GeneralStack(int)` constructor.
4. Your `isEmpty()` method will not work properly because you have an unintended semicolon after your `if` condition. `if (count == 0) ;` means 'if `count` equals zero, do nothing`. You likely intended:

   ```
   if (count == 0) {
     isEmpty = true;
   }
   ```

   In fact, the entire method can be shortened to a single statement.
5. The same issue in #3 also applies to `isFull()`, with a similar shortened form. You also have no `maxCapacity` variable in scope... perhaps you forgot to declare and initialize a field?
6. Assigning to the stack should be mutating the array element corresponding to the *top*.
7. `pop()` should not return anything if it is declared `void`. In addition, `count = count - 1` can be shortened using the *decrement operator*, `--`, e.g. `--count;`.
8. What presumably you meant to name `top()` (judging by the code of `pop()`), you accidentally named `topVal()`. Additionally, you never declare the `topVal` variable in the method scope. You can rewrite the method to obviate the need for the variable at all by directly returning the element from the array.

Comment: @Dawson since you appear newer here, please don't forget to mark the answer [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which helped most in solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> where did I go wrong?

1. It looks to me like there are some compile errors here.  e.g. you call a function `top()` that does not appear to exist (I would guess you meant `topVal()`).
2. If you want your stack to take in any type, you should look into [Generic Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).
3. In a stack, you'll want to accept the same type as a parameter for `push` that you return for `pop`.  Your `push` function accepts integers, but your `pop` function is void.
4. The array backing your data structure needs to be the same type as that used in step (2) above.  As it is now, it seems like perhaps you want that to be an integer, but as step (1) recommends, perhaps look into using a generic type.
5. In your `push` function, where you say *"not sure how to assign value to the stack"*, you should be saying `stack[count] = value`.

These things should get you started towards a working solution.  There are probably other things that need to be changed, but these are at least some of the fundamental mistakes you have made here.

Answer (score -1):

I agree please use something like arraylist. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html 
Is already implemented class but i fixed your code in case you are new to java and just are playing around with it. Did not check logic but hopefully syntax correction helps

```
    package Temp;

    public class GeneralStack
{
    int[] stack;  //not sure how to declare this
    private int count;
    private int maxCapacity;
    private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 100;

//default constructor
public GeneralStack()
    {
        stack = new int[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
        count = 0;
        maxCapacity = this.DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
    }

//alternate constructor
public GeneralStack (int maxCapacity)
    {
        stack = new int[maxCapacity];
        count = 0;
        this.maxCapacity = maxCapacity;
    }

//accessor getCount
public int getCount ()
    {
    return count;
    }

//accessor isEmpty
public boolean isEmpty ()
    {
    boolean isEmpty=false;
    if (count == 0);
        {
            isEmpty=true;
        }
    return isEmpty;
    }

//accessor isFull
public boolean isFull ()
    {
    boolean isFull=false;
    if (count == maxCapacity);
        {
        isFull=true;
        }
    return isFull;
    }

//mutator push
public void push (int value)
    {
    if (isFull ())
        {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Stack is full");
        }
    else
        {
        stack[count] = value; //not sure how to assign value to the stack
        count++;
        }
    }

// you cant return value from void function so changing it to int return you can ignore a return value 
public int pop ()
    {
         int topVal = topVal();
        count = count-1;
        return topVal;
    }

//accessor top
public int topVal ()
    {
    int topVal;
    if (isEmpty())
        {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Stack is empty");
        }
    else 
        {
        topVal=stack[count-1];
        }
    return topVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do __not__ use `Stack` when using JDK 6+. Read the [documentation on the class in JDK 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html): A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class. For example:

   `Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();`

Comment: -1 for referencing documentation to an ancient version of Java (Java 1.4, hello 2002).